# What is the different between variable declared in top level, State class and the build method of the state in fluttter?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

In flutter while dealing variables, we can declare variables at 4 places inside the state class and also outside of the class, what are the difference between these declarations and when should one used then others ?

```
String variable1 = "";

class SomeClass extends StatefulWidget {

  String variable2 = "";

  @override
  State<SomeClass> createState() => _SomeClassState();
}

class _SomeClassState extends State<SomeClass> {
  String variable3 = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
     String variable4 = "";

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- `variable1`: basically you should never use this kind of global variable for a widget. Every file you import this one to will have this variable.
- `variable2`: use this class member for non-changing parameters of a widget, preferably with `final` keyword and usually set in the constructor. For example a `Scaffold` title that is constant. Use `widget.variable2` from the state class to access these.
- `variable3`: these class members usually are used for describing the state which can change during the life cycle of the widget or are used to manage the state. It is a common practice to use  `_variable3` to indicate this is a private member. For example you can have an `bool _isProgress` variable to show a progress indicator and use `setState` to update its value from your code.
- `variable4`: any local variable you need within the build method. These are not members and will be recreated on each invocation of the build method.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I guess you missed one important case – variable1 can also be made "file-private" (or library-private) if we declare it as "_variable1". And this one is perfectly OK to use when we need a variable that should be created and assigned only once during the app runtime.